# Java load library

Tags: java

When I load library just like this :

```
String strDllFileName = m_strUserPath + "\\res\\EQ2008_Dll.dll";
        String strEQ2008_Dll_Set_Path = m_strUserPath + "\\res\\EQ2008_Dll_Set.ini";
        m_DllLibrary = (DllLibrary) Native.loadLibrary(strDllFileName,DllLibrary.class);
        m_DllLibrary.User_ReloadIniFile(strEQ2008_Dll_Set_Path);
```

I have result : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library`

How I can fix this ?

Result :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Unable to load library 'C:\Users\Krzysiek\Desktop\EQ2008_Dll_Java\res\EQ2008_Dll': 
    Nie mo?na odnale?? okre?lonego modu?
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:163)
 at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:236)
 at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:379)
 at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:364)
 at com.eq2008.Fun.main(Fun.java:274)


String strDllFileName = m_strUserPath + "\\res\\EQ2008_Dll";
        String strEQ2008_Dll_Set_Path = m_strUserPath + "\\res\\EQ2008_Dll_Set.ini";
        m_DllLibrary = (DllLibrary) Native.loadLibrary(strDllFileName,DllLibrary.class);
    m_DllLibrary.User_ReloadIniFile(strEQ2008_Dll_Set_Path);
```

Comment: What is the value of `m_strUserPath`?

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace of the error in your question.

Comment: @reporter I edit my post

Comment: @VGR I edit my post

Comment: Uhm something is strange. According your error message you tried to load a directory instead of a dedicated dll file, or do I see it wrong?

Comment: @reporter so what I do wrong?

Comment: Sometimes is not possible to load files from user profile folder. What happend if you use `C:\Temp`folder? What happend if you replace the backslash `'\'` by a forward slash `'\'`?

Comment: Based on [the documentation for com.sun.jna.Native](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html), I’m guessing you need to pass a library name, not a file path.  See [System.loadLibrary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-) for an explanation of what a library name is.

Comment: @reporter when I chamged \ to / i see this same result

Comment: @VGR could you explain me how it have to look like ?

Comment: Place your library file in the system’s library path (%PATH% in Windows, ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} in Linux, etc.), then pass the file’s base name to the `loadLibrary` method.  If the file is "EQ2008_Dll.dll" then the base name is `"EQ2008_Dll"`.  If the file only resides inside your .jar file, I’m pretty sure you cannot pass it to a loadLibrary method at all.

Comment: @VGR I did this I added this to PATH C:\Users\Desktop\Tablica\EQ2008_Dll_Java\res (here I have dll)